# How to make data displayed in Grid View auto goes to second column if there is too much data in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, gridview

I am creating some sort of Queue Management System, where the order number appears on the screen. I do not want them to be scrollable instead of I want the numbers to auto jumps to next column when the list reached the bottom of the grid view.

Here is my current sample screen:

[image]

Instead of scrolling like this I want the number 235, 234 etc.. appears on the second column which is beside the 242, 241 etc... How can I achieve this?

Below is my XAML Code:

```
        <ListView FontWeight="ExtraBold" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="50" Foreground="Blue" Width="580" Margin="0,113,0,0" Padding="30, 10, 0, 0" ItemsSource="{Binding PreparedList}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Height="514" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PPosID}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use StackPanel with Orientation="Vertical" as the ListView.ItemsPanel

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava I have updated my code in the question using both but its not working. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Bad - Use WrapPanel (I always forget names) - Also Disable the Vertical ScrollBar :-

```
    <ListView FontWeight="ExtraBold" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="50" Foreground="Blue" Width="580" Margin="0,113,0,0" Padding="30, 10, 0, 0" ItemsSource="{Binding PreparedList}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Height="514" VerticalAlignment="Top"
**ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"**>
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    **<WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" />**
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PPosID}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

This is how it looks:

[image]